# JPA Composite key (all fields are notNull and PRI)

Tags: java, jpa, composite-key

I saw that exist more then one way to map a **Composite Key** with JPA.

But in my case is kind of different:

I have a table with only 2 column:

```
mysql> desc mytable;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name   | varchar(80) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| tag    | varchar(80) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

My point is: Do I need to create a new (*primary key class*) class just to map my composite key?

I'm trying to find the easiest way to do it.

Some one can help-me?

Thanks in advance!

---

**I'm trying with this approach: http://www.java.net/print/236710**

---

Comment: Why do you want to avoid having a class for the composite primary key?

Comment: Because I will have to write a class that is almost the same as my mapping class! Just trying to simplify. 'Sound' bad code, doing that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I need to create a new (primary key class) class just to map my composite key?

To my knowledge, yes, you need to.

> I'm trying to find the easiest way to do it.

The tutorial [How to use Compound Primary Keys with Hibernate and JPA Annotations](http://jpa.ezhibernate.com/Javacode/learn.jsp?tutorial=15usingcompoundprimarykeys) does a great job at summarizing the various options (`@Id` vs `@IdClass` vs `@EmbeddedId`) and, in my opinon, the latter is the easiest way (less verbose).

Comment: Thanks for your answer/link Pascal!